# CF2018 CFSELECT Binding Failure

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2018, cfselect

The simple [city/state example](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfselect.html) in the documentation does not work in CF2018 -- I can't possibly be the first one to discover this, am I?  The state dropdown does not populate on load.  Works perfectly fine on my old install of CF11.

**Update:**

Interesting...looks like a 404 error:

```
cfmessage.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
cfajax.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
masks.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
cfform.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
binding.cfm:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: ColdFusion is not defined at binding.cfm:18 
binding.cfm:25 Uncaught ReferenceError: ColdFusion is not defined at binding.cfm:25
```

Comment: "Does not populate" ... any messages in the browser console? Have you tried wrapping it all in a try-catch block and seeing if ColdFusion has any objections?

Comment: Interesting...looks like a 404:

cfmessage.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
cfajax.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
masks.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
cfform.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
binding.cfm:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: ColdFusion is not defined
    at binding.cfm:18
binding.cfm:25 Uncaught ReferenceError: ColdFusion is not defined
    at binding.cfm:25

Comment: The example uses an XML file -- I created one.  It's using ExpandPath, which shouldn't be a problem, but I removed it and replaced it with the actual path.  Still same errors.

Comment: Thanks for the prod, TRose.  the cf_scripts virtual directory wasn't created so I created it, and boom, everything works.  I wonder if it's because this was an upgrade from CF11?

Comment: That was my next guess. Glad it worked!

Comment: You should outline the steps you took so that it will help the next person.

Comment: Good idea, James -- very simple solution.  Does the cf_scripts virtual directory exist?  If not, then just create it.  My install is on the D drive, so it looks like this: "D:\ColdFusion2018\cfusion\wwwroot\cf_scripts".

Comment: Something else I just realized -- none of my CFSELECT date CSS popups are working.  Turns out 2 two other directories weren't copied:

D:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE\scripts\ajax\resources\yui -> D:\ColdFusion2018\cfusion\wwwroot\cf_scripts\scripts\ajax\resources

and

D:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE\scripts\ajax\yui -> D:\ColdFusion2018\cfusion\wwwroot\cf_scripts\scripts\ajax

Not cool, Adobe...not cool.

Comment: Folks, keep in mind this was an upgrade from CF11 to CF2018.  If you do a clean install, I bet everything works just fine.